# How do I fix '/bin/bash/: command not found' in vim w/ rails-vim plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I'm using gvim and rails.vim and getting the following error when attempting to run `:Rake` from within a migration:

```
:!rake db:migrate VERSION=20100427002644 2>&1| tee /tmp/v436868/11 
/bin/bash/: rake: command not found
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. What can I do to fix this?

**Edit:**

If i run `rake --version` from the terminal it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like rake isn't on your path. Make sure that $PATH includes wherever the 'rake' executable is.

Comment: I agree, rake works fine from the terminal though. How do I verify that rake is available to gvim's environment?

Comment: @TheDeeno check the output of `:!echo $PATH`.

Comment: Ok, interesting. When I open gvim from an ubuntu menu my path is incorrect. However, opening from a terminal sets the correct path and the rake command works. Any idea how to change gvim's path when opened through gnome?

Comment: Try running `:!source ~/.bashrc` (or whatever rc file your shell normally reads), and then running rake from gvim.

Answer (score 0):

OP’s following comment gives a workaround, which I would consider an answer:

> When I open gvim from an ubuntu menu my path is incorrect. However, opening from a terminal sets the correct path and the rake command works.

(I don’t have enough reputation to upvote that comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Rake isn't in your `$PATH`. I suppose you're using `rvm`, which operates via `.bashrc` to add `rake` to your `$PATH`. I'm not sure `:!source ~/.bashrc` helps. Some `.bashrc` got `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` to check for an interactive session on top. Be sure the `rvm` include is above that line.

Answer (score -1):

```
[root@localhost ~]# cp /usr/local/sbin/keepalived /usr/sbin/

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/keepalived start
Starting keepalived:                                       [  OK  ]
```